# Can electromagnetic fields from high tension wires affect a garden?

Tags: growth

We can get plants (tomatoes, blueberries, grapes, etc.) to grow but they will not produce fruit. We have tried all kinds of soil. We have planted in the ground and in plant beds and in pots. we will get small green fruit and then it falls off.

Comment: Where do you live and what kind of climate do you have? How much sun does your garden get? Have you had your soil tested, and what were the results if so?

Comment: Closest study I could find in a quick search was this one where magnetic radiation actually increased yeild. http://www.old.international-agrophysics.org/artykuly/international_agrophysics/IntAgr_2010_24_3_297.pdf I'd look into answering the questions Nial C. asked first.

Comment: Do you have pictures of any of your plants? They may have visible signs that tell what is wrong with them, and/or give hints as to how to get big, ripe fruit from them. Do you water them enough?

Comment: I agree with OrganicLawn.  I've heard that an electromagnetic field actually enhances plant growth/fruit production.  What are you using for fertilization?  This is a big deal, too much nitrogen will promote only vegetative growth not reproductive/fruit.  Please give us more details and pictures...